# PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'dataset\\Thumbs.db'

Tags: python

When I run the following program、Thumbs.db looks like an image,but"PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'dataset\Thumbs.db'"It will be displayed.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# Path for face image database
path = 'dataset'

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");


# function to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):
    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
    faceSamples = []
    ids = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')  # convert it to grayscale
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img, 'uint8')

        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y + h, x:x + w])
            ids.append(id)

    return faceSamples, ids


print("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
faces, ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

# Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml')  # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi

# Print the numer of faces trained and end program
print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

Comment: It is because of a none image file `.db`. To fix it just select all files that are ends with `.jpg`. `imagePaths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.jpg')] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing Windows's `thumbs.db` file, which can't be opened as an image.

Filter your `imagePaths` to only include images:

```
imagePaths = [
    os.path.join(path, f) 
    for f 
    in os.listdir(path)
    if f.endswith(".jpg")  # <-- this `if`.
]
```

Comment: I fixed it according to the advice. But the following error occurs instantly and I don't understand this."File "Z:\OpenCV-Face-Recognition-master\OpenCV-Face-Recognition-master\FacialRecognition\02_face_training.py", line 34, in <module>
    faces, ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
  File "Z:\OpenCV-Face-Recognition-master\OpenCV-Face-Recognition-master\FacialRecognition\02_face_training.py", line 23, in getImagesAndLabels
    id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'KAEmiya'"Was it bad to display the error content here?

Comment: The code isn't equipped to understand filenames that have more than one `.`. You'll need to do something like `User_foo.123` instead of `User.foo.123` (or fix the bug)